# How can I make a content div slide over the header div as I scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

An example, http://www.laravel.com

I want to mimic this effect. I've seen it used a lot across the web lately, but I've never seen a tutorial covering how to create it.

Anyone happen to have some instructions or perhaps a tutorial on recreating this effect?

Comment: You want a sticky header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called *parallax scrolling*. You can do such things with [skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).
And [a great tutorial](https://ihatetomatoes.net/parallax-scroll-effect-scrollr-js/)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples and tutorials for sticky headers,

First link on google search for sticky header http://codepen.io/senff/pen/ayGvD

```
// Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
  $('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();

 scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


 function stickIt() {

var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               

if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
  // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

  // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
  orgElement = $('.original');
  coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
  leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
  widthOrgElement = orgElement.width();

  $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement+'px').show();
  $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
} else {
  // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
  $('.cloned').hide();
  $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
}
}
```